Allow to support <meta> tags in CKEditor5
I need to allow <meta> tags in CKEditor5. I wrote a plugin for this, but it doesn't work with these tags. But it works with another tags e.g. <custommeta>.
import {Plugin} from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core';

export default class AllowMetaElementsPlugin extends Plugin {

    init() {
        const schema = this.editor.model.schema;

        schema.register('htmlMeta', {
            allowIn: ["$root",],
            allowAttributes: ['charset', 'content', 'http-equiv', 'name'],
            isBlock: true,
            isLimit: true,
            isObject: true
        });


        const conversion = this.editor.conversion;

        conversion.for('upcast').elementToElement({
            view: 'custommeta',
            model: (viewElement, conversionApi) => {
                return conversionApi.writer.createElement('htmlMeta', viewElement.getAttributes());
            },
            converterPriority: 'highest'
        });

        conversion.for('downcast').elementToElement({
            model: {
                name: 'htmlMeta',
                attributes: ['charset', 'content', 'http-equiv', 'name']
            },
            view: (modelAttributeValue, conversionApi) => {
                return conversionApi.writer.createEmptyElement('custommeta', modelAttributeValue.getAttributes());
            },
            converterPriority: 'highest'
        });
    }
}

This works as I expected with another tag e.g. <custommeta name="AAA" content="BBB"></custommeta>. When I add this tag via Source mode and then I switch to Standard mode and then back it is still there.
But when I try this code with <meta> tag, it doesn't work (the code is the same as above, only "custommeta" is replaced by "meta"). When I add this tag <meta name="AAA" content="BBB"></meta> via Source mode and then I switch to Standard mode and then back it is not there.
import {Plugin} from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core';

export default class AllowMetaElementsPlugin extends Plugin {

    init() {
        const schema = this.editor.model.schema;

        schema.register('htmlMeta', {
            allowIn: ["$root",],
            allowAttributes: ['charset', 'content', 'http-equiv', 'name'],
            isBlock: true,
            isLimit: true,
            isObject: true
        });


        const conversion = this.editor.conversion;

        conversion.for('upcast').elementToElement({
            view: 'meta',
            model: (viewElement, conversionApi) => {
                return conversionApi.writer.createElement('htmlMeta', viewElement.getAttributes());
            },
            converterPriority: 'highest'
        });

        conversion.for('downcast').elementToElement({
            model: {
                name: 'htmlMeta',
                attributes: ['charset', 'content', 'http-equiv', 'name']
            },
            view: (modelAttributeValue, conversionApi) => {
                return conversionApi.writer.createEmptyElement('meta', modelAttributeValue.getAttributes());
            },
            converterPriority: 'highest'
        });
    }
}

